# How do I correctly add and increment integer dictionary values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

I am trying to read in data from a file. The first few characters of each line are categories, and the last few are amounts. I would like to use the first characters as keys and keep summing the last few characters into the values for their corresponding keys.

```
dak = open(filename)
zip3 = {}

for l in dak:
    y = l[:3]
    if y in zip3:
        continue
    zip3[y] = int(l[-2:])
```

After running this code I get: 
`KeyError: '006'` where 006 are the first three characters of the line. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I put my actual code in so it can be run.

Comment: Are you just looking for [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in place of a normal dict? (If not, explain why that isn't what you want.)

Comment: Meanwhile, you really shouldn't call your dict `dict`. That's the name of the type, and if you later need to use that type for anything (like building a dict out of a list of pairs, or a Counter, etc.), the error messages will be very confusing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @abamert, I named it dict just for the sample code I posted. I replaced it with my actual code. The final structure I want is a dictionary with values of quantities from a list with lines of multiple zips and quantities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code ended up working:

```
 dak = open('C:\\WIP\\SubRegions\\MMC2__86-SSX_05-07-2018-15-35-45.dak', 'r')
zip3 = {}

for l in dak:
    y = l[:3]
    if y in zip3:
        continue
    zip3[y] = 0
    zip3[y] = zip3[y] + int(l[-2:])

dak = open('C:\\WIP\\SubRegions\\MMC2__86-SSX_05-07-2018-15-35-45.dak', 'r')
for l in dak:
    y = l[:3]
    zip3[y] = zip3[y] + int(l[-2:])
```